# 2 in 1 expansion cards?

Tags: laptop, wifi, memory, wireless, data-storage

This question **will** also be on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

[image: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO. LTD. NP300E5E-A02US]

I use a `SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO. LTD. NP300E5E-A02US` and it's equipped with a single mini PCIe slot currently occupied by a `Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter`. I wish to upgrade my computer to include M.2 Flash memory capabilities but there are no extra slots to install it into. **Is there existence of such hardware that would allow me to utilize WLAN and flash storage in the same expansion slot?**

I've done extensive research and have come across nothing, the concept of integrated features within traditional tech has been explored in giving sd cards WiFi inter connectivity, granted, this isn't what I'm looking for it's just something similar. What I would like would be somewhere along the lines of a Graphics Card with some extra USB connectors on it (just an example, again not excactly what I'm looking for)

UPDATE: haha! i have found something :DDDDD, still not what I'm looking for but a great example, it's a wifi decoder and GPU in one [Hybrid Wireless Wifi HD Decoder Mini PCI-e Laptop Notebook Graphics Video Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NFSWDNG) I'm to excited to think, this may not even be what it says it is :P

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer - no such thing seems to exist.

Comment: Does your laptop even support booting off of a M.2 SSD?

Comment: Yes my laptop does support booting off of a NGFF (M.2) SSD

Comment: Nvm y'all I found what I was looking for, some m.2 egpu adapters come with a USB port meant to accept a wifi dongle